# Can I make a super plugin that also has a theme?

Tags: plugins, themes, add-theme-support

I'm working on something that requires a user to have a plugin. I only want them to have to install one thing. Can I have a plugin that has a theme with it?

Comment: Have you seen http://tgmpluginactivation.com? It might have to be packaged with your theme and on activation you could install your plugin along with any other supporting plugins.

Comment: I am almost double sure that if it is even possible it would require a huge amount of work. You can just simply ship your theme with mu plugins instead of trying to ship a theme inside a plugin

Comment: Yep. Going to put this on hold for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could always set `WP_USE_THEMES` to `false`, and handle all the template/display logic on your own. (But, that requires access to the users wp-config or index to set the constant, which is out of scope for a plugin, though you could make it an installation requirement).

Taking a look at [template-loader.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/template-loader.php) you could have an starting point to see the kind of logic you would need to reimplement.

Or otherwise you could let your users choose a theme as a fallback for all the situations not covered by your plugin, and make copious use of `template_include` to choose your plugin provieded templates on certain scenarios circumstances.

Directly from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include):

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
      $new_template = locate_template( array( 'portfolio-page-template.php' ) );
      if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template ;
    }
  }

  return $template;
}
```

At first blush I'd say that the second approach it's a bit sounder, but even then I would put more work into decoupling theme from plugin to give yourself and your users more flexibility in the future.

Comment: It seems to be much more work than asking them to install two things rather than one